# returns friends who also use your app using only facebook graph API 2.2

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-friends

I have created an application which I uses in a website for 'login through facebook' operation. Now this website has so many users who used to login through facebook. I want to retrieve only those friends who also use this app using facebook graph api version 2.2 only. **I don't need any FQL query.** As I found out lot of queries from stackoverflow, so I tried this following queries:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/me/friends?fields=installed
```

but this only returns total fb friends count.

```
{
  "data": [
  ],
  "summary": {
    "total_count": 768
  }
}
```

I also set the application access_token *'Graph API Explorer'* to my application *'newAPP'* but no result. Please help.

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23417356/facebook-graph-api-v2-0-me-friends-returns-empty-or-only-friends-who-also-u

Answer (score 1):

You don´t need to include that "installed" field, `/me/friends` will get you everyone who authorized your App. The total_count is there, so i assume the call is correct and there is only one possibility: None of your friends authorized that exact same App yet - with one of the Login solutions like [FB.login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/v2.2).